# bash: ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: cannot execute binary file

Tags: installation, command-line, bash

I am installing tool for testing.
but after download tool in folder, i try to install it by

```
root@user:~ chmod +x metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

```
root@user:~ ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

**And Output is like:**

```
bash: ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: try this time by preceding.. `sh` to your command..

Comment: i tried this output: metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: cannot execute binary file

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` command?

Comment: Just checking: you do have a 64-bit installation, right? What version? What URL did you download Metasploit from? What does `file metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run` say? P.S. @SauravKumar That message indicates that this is not a script, prepending `sh` is exactly the wrong thing to do.